# How can SQL server AlwaysOn AG can be used as a DR feature?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, disaster-recovery

I'm using AlwaysOn ag feature as a HA feature where automatic failover is possible.. I was thinking to log shipping as DR but there is potential data loss in that.. thinking of using ag as a dr(async).. is it possible? how will it work?

Answer (score 0):

AlwaysOn supports multiple replica databases, so you can have one replica as your HA database, and another replica as your DR database. AlwaysOn is great in that one technology potentially provides your HA and your DR.

The HA database would typically be in the same datacentre, and be set to synchronous commit with automatic failover. The DR database would typically be in another datacentre, but because of the latency it would typically be asynchronous as first choice. This means that data-loss is possible. You could experiment to see whether the DR replica, set as synchronous, performs well enough for your application.

Please remember that if you use AlwaysOn as your DR technology, you still need to take database backups like normal - and get them shipped off the server.

Comment: Thanks but in what ways is alwaysOn ag is suprior over log shipping as a DR feature?

Comment: @tesla747 with Availability Groups (not AlwaysOn; that's not a feature), you can ensure minimal data loss if you choose the right options and the app is properly coded - transactions can't commit on the primary unless they can also commit on the secondary. With log shipping, the primary doesn't care if backups are being taken, never mind whether they're being applied (correctly) to the secondary.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are talking about AG as DR right? HA I get it works that way. But for DR? Does both log shipping and AG in DR has potential data loss? If yes, then why would I go for AG when log shipping is there.

Comment: @tesla747 yes, with AG there are scenarios where data loss is possible. They have built-in keywords like `FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` for a reason, after all. Why would you go for AGs over log shipping? Well, that depends - it has a ton of features that aren't aren't automatic or aren't even possible in log shipping, but I have no idea if any of those features are useful for you - you'll have to do some of that research and comparison shopping on your own.